# Solution of ODE with discontinuity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb R$ be a bounded Lipschitz function and $G(x,y) = (0,\chi_{\{x \le F(y)\}})$.

Consider the ODE 
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_t \Phi(t,x) = G(\Phi), & t \in [0,T]\\
\Phi(0,x) = x & x \in \mathbb R^2
\end{cases}
$$

- How can we write the solution $\Phi$ explicitly?

Comment: BTW, this is a PDE, not an ODE. Please fix it in the question..

Comment: Also $G$ has two arguments, but you wrote $G(\Phi)$.

Comment: @user64494 $\Phi:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$. We use $\Phi_1$ as $x$ and $\Phi_2$ as $y$.

Comment: this still makes no sense; if $\Phi=(\Phi_1,\Phi_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, then $\Phi_2\in\mathbb{R}$; but in the definition of $G(x,y)$ you use $F(y)$ and if as you say $y$ should be replaced by $\Phi_2$, then you wish to evaluate the function $F$ at a point in $\mathbb{R}$, however, you have defined $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker That is a typo. Thank you. I'll edit it.

Comment: your notation is very confusing, but let me make an effort to parse it: if I only look at the first component of each of your equations, then I see that $G_1=0$, so $\partial_t\Phi_1=0$, and since $\Phi_1=x_1$ at $t=0$, I conclude that $\Phi_1=x_1$ at all $t$. Is that what you want?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Yes. And the real problem is computing $\Phi_2$.

Answer (score 1):

OK, from the comments I understand that the problem boils down to

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Phi_2(t,x_1,x_2)=\theta\bigl(F[\Phi_2(t,x_1,x_2)]-x_1\bigr),\;\;\Phi_2(0,x_1,x_2)=x_2,$$

where $\theta$ is the unit step function. Let me assume that $F$ is a nondecreasing function. Then the solution is

$$\Phi_2(t,x_1,x_2)=\begin{cases}
t+x_2&\text{if}\;\;F(x_2)>x_1\\
x_2&\text{if}\;\;F(x_2)\leq x_1.
\end{cases}
$$

A more general choice of $F$ can be readily accommodated, by piecing together increasing and decreasing segments. For any $F$, the function $\Phi_2(t,x_1,x_2)=x_2$ whenever $F(x_2)\leq x_1$, so we only need to consider regions in which $F(x_2)>x_1$ and $\Phi_2$ increases linearly with $t$ until $F(\Phi_2)$ becomes smaller than $x_1$.

---

as requested, the Mathematica code

`Manipulate[Module[{sol = 
             NDSolve[{phi2'[t] == UnitStep[Sin[phi2[t]] - x1], phi2[0] == x2}, 
                      phi2, {t, 0, tfinal}]}, 
             Plot[Evaluate[phi2[t] /. sol], {t, 0, tfinal}]], 
                           {x1, 0, 2}, {x2, 0, 2}, {tfinal, 1, 10}]`

will produce a plot of $\Phi_2(t)$ (for $F=\sin$) where you can vary $t_{\rm final}$, $x_1$, and $x_2$.

alternatively, the Mathematica code

`sol = NDSolve[{D[phi2[t, x1, x2], t] == 
               UnitStep[Sin[phi2[t, x1, x2]] - x1], phi2[0, x1, x2] == x2}, phi2, 
               {t, 0, 5}, {x1, 0, 2}, {x2, 0, 2}];
 Manipulate[VectorPlot[{x1, Evaluate[phi2[t, x1, x2] /. sol]}, 
               {x1, 0, 2}, {x2, 0, 2}], {t, 0, 5}]
 Manipulate[StreamPlot[{x1, Evaluate[phi2[t, x1, x2] /. sol]}, 
               {x1, 0, 2}, {x2, 0, 2}], {t, 0, 5}]`

will produce a vector plot or a stream plot of $(\Phi_1,\Phi_2)$ in the $x$-$y$ plane, with $t$ as a parameter that you can vary.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

A remark, too long for a comment. Let use the notation $H=\mathbf 1_{\mathbb R_+}$. You have to deal with an ODE whose flux is
$$
a(x,y)=H(F(y)-x),
$$
where $F$ is a Lipschitz-continuous function, $x$ is a parameter. We have also formally
$$
\frac{\partial a}{\partial y}=\delta_0(F(y)-x)F'(y),
$$
and assuming as in the previous answer that $F$ is monotone (say increasing), the rhs qualifies as the line-measure on the manifold with equation $F(y)=x$. As  a result the 
flux is $BV$. Although there is a good theory for flow of $BV$ vector fields (say with bounded divergence), the second picture in the previous answer seems to indicate a non-uniqueness phenomenon, maybe related to the fact that the divergence of the vector field is unbounded.